# How do I display a text file in a browser without the text wrapping?

Tags: asp.net, html, jquery-ui, browser, text

My web application generates files. I have a web page that displays links to these files. When I click the link, I get the file displayed in the browser(IE8) but the texted is wrapping making it hard to read. To work around this I would "view source" on the page then turn off the word wrap.

Is there any way to load a text file into a bowser and preserve the line breaks, with no wrapping? Do I need a special web component?

Thanks.

Comment: When non-html files display in a browser it happens with browser extensions.  It depends on what kind of file you are creating as to whether you can update the way the extension behaves.  You have not given us a file type.

Comment: plain text file with a .log extention

Comment: It could help to wrap it in `<pre>...</pre>` tags? This assuming it is shown inside a web page...

Answer (score 0):

This is a technical quirk associated with IE8.  I'm unable to reproduce it in IE9 as IE9 simply opens the file with notepad (or likely the program associated with .xxx extension).  There's a workaround on Microsoft [forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/viewing-txt-files-in-ie8/3e323f66-14dd-4d6b-bff9-38ed41cf9a8e).  It amounts to changing the Save As type from **HTML Document** to **All Files**.

Comment: I don't get the download dialog, the file just opens in the browser.